# Unable to left align entire web-part contents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, web-part

I created a standard contact library web part but when i place it on my page it will only right align.  The title "Contact Library" will align left when i go in to Web Part settings > Layout and click "Left to Right" under direction, but the other features like "new item or edit this item +" and the column names are aligned right.  Its driving me mad!

I get this....

[image: SP - Web Part - Align]

Anyone know how to change this.  I am happy to try adding to the code but do not know what to add or where to add it.  If i can be guided through that i could do it.  Although my organisation is a little restrictive when it comes to modifying the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you inspect your elements using browser developer tool (F12) and see any of your styles causing this issue.